# Service Fabric redeployment does not reach healthy state

Tags: azure-service-fabric

For deploying an application on our Windows Fabric standalone cluster, we use the Service Fabric API.
Currently we are having issues with redeployment. A new fresh deployment is okay. When the application already exists, we remove it first, but the new application does not reach a healthy state.

Any suggestions on what it can be/what is wrong? Do we need some timeout between removing and deploying?

```
// Clean up previous deployment.
var application = (await fabricClient.QueryManager.GetApplicationListAsync(applicationUri).ConfigureAwait(false)).SingleOrDefault();
if(application != null)
{
    // Removing application instance...
    await fabricClient.ApplicationManager.DeleteApplicationAsync(new DeleteApplicationDescription(applicationName)
    {
    ForceDelete = true
    }).ConfigureAwait(false);
}

var applicationType = (await fabricClient.QueryManager.GetApplicationTypeListAsync(applicationTypeName).ConfigureAwait(false)).SingleOrDefault();
if(applicationType != null)
{
    // Unregistering application type...
    await fabricClient.ApplicationManager.UnprovisionApplicationAsync(applicationTypeName, applicationTypeVersion).ConfigureAwait(false);
}

// Create the new deployment
// Copying application package...
fabricClient.ApplicationManager.CopyApplicationPackage(imageStoreConnectionString, applicationPackageDirectoryPath, applicationTypeName);

// Registering application type...
await fabricClient.ApplicationManager.ProvisionApplicationAsync(applicationTypeName).ConfigureAwait(false);

// Creating application...
await fabricClient.ApplicationManager.CreateApplicationAsync(new ApplicationDescription(applicationUri, applicationTypeName, applicationTypeVersion)).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: Is there any errors or warnings in the Service Fabric Explorer? Or what `Get-ServiceFabricApplicationHealth` does return if you user PowerShell?

Comment: Yeah look for health errors/warnings with exception messages or stack traces. From Service Fabric's viewpoint, this should work, but there could be any number of things in your service code causing a problem. Btw, why are you blowing the application away and re-deploying instead of doing rolling upgrades? This is pretty risky in a production environment.

Comment: Not all of our services are going down. The `Get-ServiceFabricApplicationHealth` returns for some of our services `AggregatedHealthState : Error`. We now added some extra retries because we found one _FabricNotReadableException_.

Vaclav Turecek: We are not using rolling upgrade because we are doing blue-green deployment (we have two SF applications per app: a blue and a green application). Therefore we remove the inactive one when we deploy a new version.